# I want some specific characters from the link

Tags: javascript, react-native

The link like this i want only this `suyashvashishtha@axl` and this address can be dynamic eg: `anyaddress0005446556@axl,newaddress@axl` i only want this character from `pa=` to `&`. Please help me.

```
upi://pay?pa=suyashvashishtha@axl&pn=Suyash%20Vashishtha&mc=0000&mode=02&purpose=00
```

I was splitting it but the address is dynamic of different users this method is not working..

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Comment: Like this: `/pa=([^&]*)/`

Comment: Use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor: `new URL(url).searchParams.get("pa")`